# How to execute commands inside a shell using Process object in Java

Tags: java, process

I executed a shell using:

```java
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("docker exec rabbitmq bash");
```

But now, I want to execute another command inside the opened shell:

```java
Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
w.write("rabbitmqctl list_queues\n");
w.flush();
```

But I can't get the output of `rabbitmqctl list_queues`

```java
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

I don't get any errors, if I use a malformed command, it will issue an error message:

```java
BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
String errorString = error.readLine();
System.out.println("\nError : " + errorString);

int exitCode = process.waitFor();
```

Comment: @Jesse, Hello, I don't think so, it's strange, but the output is about the main process piped to input of child process.

Comment: Yeah that looks to be correct. I'm more used to C# where it's the other way around.

Comment: If you were issuing that command at the command line what exactly would it be?

Comment: Hi @g00se, I get two lines: `Timeout: 60.0 seconds ...
Listing queues for vhost / ...`

Comment: I don't know docker but I'm thinking there must be a way of sending batch commands to it. It should be one command and then you get the results and it terminates

Comment: thanks @g00se, executing: `docker exec rabbitmq rabbitmqctl list_queues` it worked

Comment: Good. `Runtime.exec` has been superseded by `ProcessBuilder`. If you use that you'll get more control.

Comment: @g00se, I have found the solution using ProcessBuilder, I'll add an answer, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the lack of use of `-i` parameter:

```java
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("docker exec -i rabbitmq bash");
```

But, using only Process class I had had problems, the interpreter didn't understand the end of output and the loop didn't stop:

```java
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

But using ProcessBuilder it worked:

```java
    @Test
    void test_process_builder() throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("docker","exec","-i","rabbitmq3","bash");
        Process process = builder.start();

        OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream(); // <- Eh?
        InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
        InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));
        BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stderr));

        writer.write("rabbitmqctl list_queues \n");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        Scanner err = new Scanner(stderr);
        while (err.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(err.nextLine());
        }
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stdout);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }
    }
```